# my program doesn't check the else-if statement

Tags: java

i'm still new to coding so please bear with me. my program always check what's going on in the if statement and doesn't go to else-if statement even the value is false. So, why does that happen? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= time; i++) { System.out.println("Clock loop = " + i);

        for (int j = 0; j < cashierArr.length; j++) {
            System.out.println("CashierArr at " + j + "  is busy? "
                    + cashierArr[j].busy);
            System.out.println(j);

            if (cashierArr[j].busy = true) {

                cashierArr[j].serveTime -= 1;
                System.out.println("Serve time = "
                        + cashierArr[j].serveTime);
                System.out.println("In busy");

            } else if (cashierArr[j].busy = false) {


                Customer tempCust = (Customer) queue.poll();


                cashierArr[j].serveTime = tempCust.serviceTime;
                System.out
                        .println("serveTime = " + cashierArr[j].serveTime);
                cashierArr[j].busy = true;

                System.out.println("In not busy");
            }

        }
```

Comment: if (cashierArr[j].busy = true) should be just if (cashierArr[j].busy) and for (cashierArr[j].busy = false) try (!cashierArr[j].busy)

Comment: you need to add '=='(double) not '='(single) in if and if else condition. Secondly, if busy is the Boolean type no need to check equality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

please , do following ,

```
if (cashierArr[j].busy ==  true) { // == is comparison operator, while = is assign
```

> you have used only single assignment which will actually assign the
>   value to true means it's always remains **true**

```
if (cashierArr[j].busy =  true)
```

Comment: or just  `if (cashierArr[j].busy)`

Answer (score 1):

```
1) if(cashierArr[j].busy = true)   

2) else if (cashierArr[j].busy = false)
```

In above statement you are use `(=)`assignment operator `not (==)`comparison operators.

`= Operator` is use for assign value not comparison so It's actually assign the

value to `true` means it is always result `true` so your `else statement` never gets to be execute ever.

> change == in both statement

```
1) if(cashierArr[j].busy == true)   

2) else if (cashierArr[j].busy == false)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a basic syntax issue change

it assigns value true and false to  cashierArr[j].busy

`if (cashierArr[j].busy = true)`  to  `if (cashierArr[j].busy == true)`

and

`else if (cashierArr[j].busy = false)` to   `else if (cashierArr[j].busy == false`)

Assuming your code might be using Boolean for busy field and you dont want to do anything in case of null.

Answer (score 0):

when you do this:

```
if (cashierArr[j].busy = true) {
```

you are assigning the variable to true and not checking the value in there...

and since you are checking booleans it it enough to write:

```
if (cashierArr[j].busy) {
```